# when I press the button it doesn't work addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I hope you are very well, I have a problem with my 'addEventListener', I do not know what is wrong exactly or how to solve it, I'm not sure.

**What I want to do is:**
Press the button and after it is pressed the button event appears on the console.

**when I check down the last line it says:**
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

**Javascript code:**

```
class Student {
  constructor(name, lastName, carreer, university, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.carreer = carreer;
    this.university = university;
    this.email = email;
  }
}

class User {
  constructor() {
    this.userList = [];
    this.id = 0;
  }

  addUser(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5) {
    let id = this.id;

    this.userList.push({
      id: id,
      student: new Student(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5)
    });

    this.id += 1;
  }

  allUserList() {
    return this.userList;
  }

  updateUserById(id) {
    //Code here
  }

  findUserById(id) {
    //Code here
  }

  removeUserById(id) {
    //Code here
  }

  drawTable(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = `col-md-4`;

    div.style = `background: #ffffff;
      width: 200px;
      height: auto;
      margin-left: 15px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      border: solid 1px black;
      width: 320px;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 25px;
      `;

    div.innerHTML = `
      <form class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3 text-left" style="padding-top: 5%;">
      <label><strong>Student form</strong></label>
      <label>DNI: ${val1}</label>
      <label>Name: ${val2}</label>
      <label>Last name: ${val3}</label>
      <label>Carreer: ${val4}</label>
      <label>University: ${val5}</label>
      <label>E-mail: ${val6}</label>
      </form>
      `;

    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}

/*
//TESTING:
// Instance of User() class
const user = new User();

// Creating users:
user.addUser(
  "Matias",
  "Paredes",
  "Ing. Informatica",
  "Universidad X",
  "micorreo@gmail.com"
);
user.addUser(
  "Javier",
  "Rabb",
  "Ing. Sistemas",
  "Universidad X",
  "micorreo@gmail.com"
);
user.addUser(
  "Francisco",
  "Manu",
  "Ing. Teleco",
  "Universidad X",
  "micorreo@gmail.com"
);

// Show all users:
console.log(user.allUserList());

//END OF TESTING.
*/

class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.inputList = [];
    this.buttonList = [];
  }

  allInputs() {
    this.inputList.push({
      inputDNI: document.getElementById("inputDniId"),
      inputName: document.getElementById("inputNameId"),
      inputLastName: document.getElementById("inputLastNameId"),
      inputCarreer: document.getElementById("inputCarreerId"),
      inputUniversity: document.getElementById("inputUniversityId"),
      inputEmail: document.getElementById("inputEmailId")
    });
  }

  allButtons() {
    this.buttonList.push({
      submitButton: document.getElementById("submitId"),
      checkDataButton: document.getElementById("checkDataId")
    });
  }
}

// Instance of:
const control = new Controller();
const user = new User();
// Submit button:
const submitControl = control.buttonList.submitButton
// Event listener draw table and assign values:
const input = control.inputList.find((e) => e.inputName)

submitControl.addEventListener(
 "click", (e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: well button list is an array so not sure how you expect `control.buttonList.submitButton` to work on an array

Comment: You never called `control.allButtons()`. So `control.buttonList` is an empty array.

Comment: `control.inputList.find((e) => e.inputName)` shouldn't you be looking for a specific value of `e.inputName`?

Comment: It's not clear why `inputList` and `buttonList` are arrays. It seems like they should each be a single object.